# how to match or get dynamic value from another cell based on multiple criteria in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup, multiple-conditions

This sheet i want to fill out and based on the values i choose here, the value in cell G
should be copied to the sheet Sittard

[image: This sheet i want to fill out and based on the values i choose here, the value in cell G should be copied to the sheet Sittard]

The sheet Sittard looks like this
[image: Sittard Sheet where the value should be based]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C; 
 {Inkoop!D2:D&Inkoop!E2:E&Inkoop!F2:F\ Inkoop!G2:G}; 2; 0)))
```

or in D1:

```
={"Stukprijs"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C; 
 {Inkoop!D2:D&Inkoop!E2:E&Inkoop!F2:F \Inkoop!G2:G}; 2; 0)))}
```